# Pivot Table with filtered column

Tags: google-sheets, sum, pivot-table, google-sheets-formula

I have a pivot table in google sheets that references source data in a separate tab. Here's example raw data contained in the tab "MAR21 Powders" (only included the pertinent fields):

```
Jar Type      Qty     Needed In Next 2 Weeks
Black Jar     500            Yes
White Jar     500           
White Jar     500            Yes
Clear Jar     1000           Yes
```

Right now, my pivot table only looks at the Jar Type and the Qty columns and does a SUM of the Qty field. The range is: 'MAR 21 Powder'!A1:W235

Here is the pivot table output on a tab called "Pivots":

```
Jar Type      Qty
Black Jar     500
White Jar     1000
Clear Jar     1000
```

I would like to have a 3rd column that takes that "Needed in the Next 2 Weeks" column into account and displays the following:

```
Jar Type      Qty      Qty Needed In Next 2 Weeks
Black Jar     500                 500
White Jar     1000                500
Clear Jar     1000                1000
```

As you can see, the 3rd column only adds the qty if the "Needed In the Next 2 Weeks" column says "Yes" within the source data on the "MAR21 Powders" tab. So, for the White Jars, 1000 are needed in total but only 500 are needed in the next 2 weeks.

How would I go about this to be able to add this 3rd column to the pivot table? Or, if it's easier, how can I add a global filter at the top of the page that let's me filter on "Needed In the Next 2 Weeks = Yes" keeping in mind I have a separate pivot for Jars, Lids, and Scoops. So, it would need to work for all 3 at once.

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a column to the right of the "Needed In Next 2 Weeks" Yes/No column on your raw data.

Assuming that raw data you showed here is in columns A:C (i know it's not, just for the sake of explanation)

so in column D, title the column:"Qty Needed In Next 2 Weeks", then you would put `=IF(C2="Yes",B2,0)`

Now you should have a new column available in your pivot table to sum and you can add it like you would any other Field.

Comment: It's so funny...about 5 minutes before you posted this I had a lightbulb moment and did this exact thing. Was just about to delete the thread and saw this. Thanks so much for the answer. Glad we're on the same page with this solution. Have a great day!